# Uninstall the Kubuntu environment

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu

Hi I downloaded the kde desktop environment through the terminal on ubuntu 14.04 and i cant find out how to delete it. Also every time i restart my pc it goes to the kubuntu boot and login screen. Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works but if it is a OS you can boot from Ubuntu live Cd and install OS un-installer- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

or you can go to your computer setup when it boots up and change hard-drive to boot from.
(my first answer)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, thanks though i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you logout and then login back to Unity? (You were in Unity, rite?)

If yes and what you did was to install the meta package `kde-desktop` then there is a list of all the software installed, upgraded and uninstalled in the Ubuntu Software Center application (under the 'History' tab).

Theoretically by uninstalling the packages installed (only remove the ones under the Installed tab, do not touch the upgraded ones) by kde-desktop meta package  you should be able of uninstalling the workspace.

All the packages you need to remove can be identified by looking at the installation date. All are from the same date and time and they are a lot...

Remember to first make a backup.

But if yo can login back to Unity, you might aswell just make Unity your default workspace again and be happy. The Kubuntu splash screen shouldn't be a big problem to switch back to the first one either.